# How to calculate the % wins of a dataframe column "match_outcome"

Tags: r

Hi guys I just started a few weeks ago so sorry if this is very easy.

I have a dataframe with a column that is called "game_outcome". The rows are either "win" or "loss". I would like calculate the % of wins

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, here are a couple of ways

```
# sample data frame
df = data.frame(game_outcome=sample(c("win", "lose"), 100, replace = T), a=1, b=NA)

# get counts for each category and find proportion
table(df$game_outcome) / nrow(df)

lose  win 
0.53 0.47 

# for only one case
sum(df$game_outcome == "win") / nrow(df)

0.47
```